# Checkin to a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, checkin, django-facebook

I got a page on Facebook and i want to know how come people can't check in on my page? I tried checking in and it came up with a different page and i have merged the pages together but it still not working. Can you please let me know if my need to change any settings.